# how to Permanently disable mark item as read when selection changes in outlook

Tags: outlook

I have a user who keeps reporting that emails are being read when they are not double clicking them. I have changed disabled "Mark item as read when selection changes" several times only for her to call me back a day or two later because it's happening again. I check the settings and sure enough "Mark item as read when selection changes" is enabled again. Is there a hotkey for this setting I am not aware of? I have tried the registry hack below but it didn't work. The setting was not greyed out and I could still change it

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\Preferences

Value Type： DWORD

Value Name： previewdontmarkuntilchange

Valued: 1

TL;DR - "Mark item as read when selection changes" keeps getting enabled somehow, anyway to permanently disable it?

[image: This setting in Outlook]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all add-ins and outlook rules. I'm not sure what was the culprit but doing this has prevented the above from being enabled randomly.